# Find a consistent estimator for $E[X^2]$ when $X \sim \text{Exp}(\beta)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, variance, parameter-estimation

I am working on this problem.

Find a consistent estimator for $E[X^2]$ when $X \sim  \text{Exp}(\beta)$ .

So far I am thinking of using the invariant property of MLEs, so I let

$$\hat{\theta} = \bar{X}$$

And since $E[X^2]=2\beta^2$ and $E[\bar{X}^2]=\beta^2(1/n+1)$ I thought that

$$\hat{\theta_2}=2\bar{X}$$
would be better since it is now asymptotically unbiased.

Now I want to show that $\operatorname{Var}[\hat{\theta_2}] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but I am stuck because I don't know what to do after I get

$$4\operatorname{Var}[\bar{X}^2]$$

May I have some help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\mathsf{Exp}$ with mean $\beta$, then by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law)

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\stackrel{P}\longrightarrow E(X_1^2)=2\beta^2$$

So a consistent estimator of $2\beta^2$ based on a sample of $n$ observations is simply $T_1=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2$.

Similarly, with $\overline X=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ we have $$\overline X\stackrel{P}\longrightarrow \beta$$

And by continuous mapping theorem, $$2\overline X^2\stackrel{P}\longrightarrow 2\beta^2$$

So regarding your idea, another consistent estimator is $T_2=2\overline X^2$.

If you wish to find the large sample variance of $T_2$, then you can use a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables#Second_moment) on $g(x)=2x^2$ to arrive at

$$\operatorname{Var}\left[2\overline X^2\right]\approx \operatorname{Var}\left[\overline X\right](g'(\beta))^2=\frac{16\beta^4}{n} $$

Comment: OK!  So I can basically say by the law of large numbers $\bar{X} \rightarrow_P E[X]$ since $f(x) = 2x^2$ is a continuous function, $f(\bar{X}) \rightarrow_P f(E(X))$ right?

Comment: @hyg17 Yes, that's what the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) says.